# Issue Running Kafka 2.11-2.3.0

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka

I was following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os) tutorial for kafka on windows.
I am able to run zookeeper but while running kafka i am facing issue.

By running below command

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

I am getting below error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class File\kafka
```

I am not able to figure it our where i am going wrong.
Please suggest corrections

Comment: Have you added `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in your classpath?

Comment: Hi @GiorgosMyrianthous Thanks for replying. Yes I have %JAVA_HOME%\bin path in my environment variables

Comment: This has nothing to do with Kafka. Could not find or load main class is Java related error.

Comment: What is `File\kafka`? Where did you extract the Kafka package? This path cannot contain any spaces

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank You very much. Yes my path had spaces ,after removing that it started working properly. And I don't know what is File\kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cricket_007 Thanks for identifying the issue. It happened because my path had spaces. After removing spaces from my path it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it from within the windows `bin` directory.  That is, `cd` to the directory first, and then, from there, run the command:

```
cd bin/windows

kafka-server-start.bat ..\config\server.properties
```

Note the reference to the parent directory, and then back to `config`, to get the correct location for the `server.properties` file.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried this it didn't worked. Actual issue was that my path had spaces.